# I want to get selected radio button value

Tags: asp.net

I want to get selected radio button value ,my all radio buttons in a same Group,please Help

my Source is below :-

```
   <td><p>Communication</p></td>
                      <td>
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RB1" runat="server" value="1" GroupName="GrRatingGrp" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                      </td>
                     <td>
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RB2" runat="server" value="2" GroupName="GrRatingGrp" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                      </td>
                     <td>
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RB3" runat="server" value="3" GroupName="GrRatingGrp" onclick="ShowHideDiv()"/>
                      </td>
                     <td>
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RB4" runat="server" value="4" GroupName="GrRatingGrp" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                      </td>
                     <td>
                          <asp:RadioButton ID="RB5" runat="server" value="5" GroupName="GrRatingGrp" onclick="ShowHideDiv()"/>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
```

Comment: A RadioButton Control does not have `value` property. You cannot invent your own and expect aspnet to read them in code behind. You need to use `Attributes`.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend using Radio Button list if all radio buttons are in the same group.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Data</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Data1</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

You can set AutoPostBack to true to get the value in Code Behind or you can also get the selected value in Javascript/Jquery at Client Side like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#RadioButtonList1").on("change", function () {
            var abc = $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:checked').val();
            alert(abc);
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RadioButtonList instead of separate Radio buttons.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtlist" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" >2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

If you want to get selected value using C# code then use SelectedIndex,SelectedValue or SelectedItem.Text methods.

```
 string val=rbtlist.SelectedValue;
```